# Using a CTE table as part of `START WITH` clause in recursive query

Tags: oracle, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I don't seem to be able to use a CTE table as part of the below recursive query?

I have two CTE tables. One that gets a bunch of grouper codes and another that explodes those grouper codes out into the "child codes" (exploded_codes) that I want to use in the below query. When I add the EXPLODED_CODES CTE table into the IN() clause of my main query (shown below), no data is returned (no error though). However, if I hard code the values that are returned from a simple select statement on the EXPLODED_CODES CTE table, into the IN() clause, the query returns as expected! Any clue why this may be?

Here is my recursive query. Is there any reason anyone can think of that using the CTE table wouldnt work, but hard coding the values that the CTE table contains would? I know it has something to do with the recursion logic because when I change `starts with` to `where` and comment out the `connect by` clause, it returns some data (although its not the full parent-child hierarchy that the recursive query returns using the hard coded values.

```
    select *
    from events 
    start with 
    events.event_cd in (
                                select event_cd from exploded_codes --This code returns no data
                                --22600750,135148330,107919568 --These are the values in the CTE and returns correct data

                             )
    connect by nocycle ((prior parent_event_id = event_id and prior event_id <> event_id)  
    or (prior event_id = parent_event_id) )
```

Comment: Post a *reproducible* example pls and let us not speculate. There is a *good change* that while you are working on it you'll find the problem.

Comment: I wish I could reproduce it. Unfortunately, I cant!

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially all I am trying to do. However, it works fine in my mock ups like this:

```
    with mytable as (
    select 1 as pk1, 123 as event_id, 123 as parent_event_id, 777 as event_cd from dual
    union select 2, 456, 123, 777 as event_cd from dual
    union select 3, 756, 423, 999 as event_cd from dual
    )
    --select * from mytable
    , codes as (
    select 777 as event_cd from dual union select 88 as event_cd from dual union 
    select 111 as event_cd from dual
    )

    select myTable.*--, level, SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(event_id, '/') as path
    from 
    myTable  
    start with event_cd in (select event_cd from codes)  
    connect by nocycle (prior parent_event_id = event_id and prior event_id <> event_id)
    or (prior event_id = parent_event_id)
```

However, when I query my actual database table, it returns no rows depending on how I populate the CTE table (event though my table ends up with the same values each way.

What I cant seem to understand is that when I uncomment the below line from my `CODES` table, is when my recursive query doesnt return anything. However, when I hard code the values in like I am below, my recursive query returns fine. I have tried casting the datatype to NUMBER (which is how event_cd is stored in the EVENT table) and that has no affect.

```
    with codes as (
    --This method of populating the table causes my recursive query to not return anything 
    --select xcode from xr_template_codes where xtype = 'event-set' and SECTION_DISPLAY = 'Coding Summary'
      --So does this method (which is the equivalent of the above).
      --select xcode from xr_template_codes where  xcode = 107919402
      --union
      --select xcode from xr_template_codes where xcode = 101320306
      --This method seems to work fine. These are just the two values returned from the XR_TEMPLATES_CODES table.
      select 101320306 as event_cd from dual union select 107919402 as event_cd from dual
      
    )

    select *
    from 
         event       
    start with 
    event.event_cd in (select to_number(event_cd) from codes)
    and event.id = 15169295                              
  
    connect by nocycle (prior parent_event_id = event_id and prior event_id <> event_id)
     or (prior event_id = parent_event_id)
```